# db2 connection failing after migrating from iis7.5 to iis8.5

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, db2, odbc, iis-8.5

I have a classic ASP web application which connects to a DB2 database to read some data. i migrated the application from windows server 2008r2(IIS7.5) to 2012r2(IIS8.5) and the application is not able to establish a connection to the database. i get below error
`ERROR [HY000] [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C An unexpected system error occurred. SQLSTATE=58004 ERROR [HY000] [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C An unexpected system error occurred. SQLSTATE=58004`

my web.config
`<add key="DB2TDSNName" value="Driver={{IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER}};DBALIAS=DB2T;Uid={0};Pwd={1};" />`

i use the above ODBC connection to connect to the database. It is working fine in IIS7.5 but not IIS8.5. should i be doing anything different in 8.5?

Note: i added a system DSN in ODBC data source and the connection was successful, somehow the application hosted from IIS is not able to establish a connection.

Comment: Does IIS 8.5 use an ODBC connection? If so, can you see that DSN , and can you connect with the same credentials as IIS 8.5 on that DSN (via odbcad32).

Comment: Also check whether the account that IIS 7.5 uses for db2-connection has correct rights/privileges on 2012r2.  Check if there is a db2diag.log file present on the 2012r2 and view its contents (text file, most recent entries at the end).

Comment: @mao i dint find ODBC connection in IIS, the account used for DB2 connection doesnt have any rights on the 2008r2 either. i cannot find db2diag.log on 2012r2. where can i find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out what the issue is. the environment variable for DB2 driver was not properly declared in System environment variables. i added it to the Path environment variables and it is working.